# Cube Flip animation for Fragments on Android

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to implement a basic 3d cube and rotate it by 90degrees either horizontally or vertically on Touch. What i want to implement is something similar to what is shown in the image below.

I've achieved this using `ViewPager`'s `ViewTransformer` 
But I am not happy with the result. The animation is not very smooth, and i cannot flip it, i have to drag my finger across the entire widht of the screen to rotate the cube.
I want to just flip it, but am not able to achieve it.

[image][image]

I've used [BTGridPager-Android](https://github.com/btate/BTGridPager-Android) to achieve the above. But as mentioned, its not very convincing.

Here is my ViewTransformer code:

```
    public abstract class ABaseTransformer implements PageTransformer {
 @Override
 public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
  onPreTransform(page, position);
  onTransform(page, position);
  onPostTransform(page, position);
 }
protected void onPreTransform(View page, float position) {
  final float width = page.getWidth();

  page.setRotationX(0);
  page.setRotationY(0);
  page.setRotation(0);
  page.setScaleX(1);
  page.setScaleY(1);
  page.setPivotX(0);
  page.setPivotY(0);
  page.setTranslationY(0);
  page.setTranslationX(isPagingEnabled() ? 0f : -width * position);

  if (hideOffscreenPages()) {
   page.setAlpha(position <= -1f || position >= 1f ? 0f : 1f);
  } else {
   page.setAlpha(1f);
  }
 }


public class HorizontalCubeOutTransformer extends ABaseTransformer {

 @Override
 protected void onTransform(View view, float position) {

  final float normalizedposition = Math.abs(1 - Math.abs(position));

  view.setPivotX(position < 0f ? view.getWidth() : 0f);
  view.setPivotY(view.getHeight() * 0.5f);
  view.setRotationY(90f * position);
  view.setAlpha(normalizedposition);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isPagingEnabled() {
  return true;
 }

}



public class VerticalCubeOutTransformer extends ABaseTransformer {


 @Override
 protected void onTransform(View view, float position) {

  final float normalizedposition = Math.abs(Math.abs(position) - 1);
  view.setAlpha(normalizedposition);
  view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);
  view.setTranslationY(position * view.getHeight());

  view.setPivotX(view.getWidth() * 0.5f);
  view.setPivotY(position < 0f ? view.getHeight() : 0f);
  view.setRotationX(90f * -position);

 }

 @Override
 public boolean isPagingEnabled() {
  return false;
 }
}
```

What I would like to know is how to rotate the cube on the flip gesture.
Note: I would like to achieve this without OpenGL or SurfaceView.

**UPDATE:** 
till now i have implemented the cube flip using fragmenttransactionExtended but now i got some other problem, as the current fragment disappears as soon as the flip begins

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use FragmentTransactionExtended

[FragmentTransactionExtended](https://github.com/DesarrolloAntonio/FragmentTransactionExtended)

it provides all types of animations between frgaments

Comment: Hi Shashidhar, Is is possible to do it with all direction? (Horizontal and Vertical) at a time.

Comment: i have never done that but you can look into that source code and combine that animations.

Comment: Hey @SHASHIDHARMANCHUKONDA, I have implemented the cube like transaction using FragmentTransactionExtended, but now issue is while doing the transaction, the current fragment get destroy before the transaction began, and next fragment is is working fine (transaction looks like next fragment is scrolled in cube fashion)

Comment: @inni I'm attempting to also have a cube of fragments. Could you post how your got the vertical flip to work? FragmentTransactionExtended only has horizontal flips. BTW, you could use a Bundle to save the instance state and load it later