# Transformation on PagerTabStrip or animation on PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer, pagertitlestrip

I have implemented a PagerTabstrip successfully with my viewpager as given below.

```
<com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/my_PageTabStrip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" />
    </com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager>
```

My tabs are showing in default animation, how can I change the animation of pagerTabstrip?

I think one solution is edit the pagerTitlestrip which extended by pagerTabstrip, Any one have idea about that??

Answer (score 0):

Refer the links,
https://code.google.com/p/transitionviewpager/source/browse/#git%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fabhi%2Ftransitionviewpager%253Fstate%253Dclosed

and

[Cube Flip animation for Fragments on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867541/cube-flip-animation-for-fragments-on-android)

Comment: I implemented the transition effect on viewpager, I need to change the same in PagerTabStrip